# How to show a custom field/label above the short description only for logged-in users in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I am using WooCommerce with an Avada template and need to have a field/label that allows manual input of percentages at the product level via admin (each product needs to have the ability to enter different percentages), which then shows up front-end, under a short description but only when logged in. This is quite out of my wheelhouse so hoping someone can assist me.

Issue 1: I currently have field/label sitting where it is as I don't know the code to get it to show above the short description
Issue 2: I don't know what code to add to have the field/label only display when logged in.

See screenshots for the current front-end display and also the admin.
[Front-end view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmmcp.jpg)
[Admin Product view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpiOv.jpg)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can render assistance. Have a great day! :)

Code created thus far is below:

```
// Add a Custom Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field', 
            'label'       => __( 'Markup', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '100.00%',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'If you do not save any % value It cannot be seen, 'woocommerce' ) 
        )
    );

}

// Save the custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if( ! empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}
/**
 *  Display a custom product field before a short description in WooCommerce
 */

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'magik_custom_text', 11);
function magik_custom_text()
{
    global $post;
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    // Displaying the custom field only when is set with a value
    if( ! empty( $field_value ) )
        echo '<p>' . __('Markup: ', 'woocommerce'). $field_value . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook instead of `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form` to show the `Markup` field above the short description. and, You can use the `is_user_logged_in()` wordpress function to check whether the user is logged in or not.

```
// Display the custom field above the short description
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'magik_custom_text', 15);
function magik_custom_text() {
    global $post;
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_text_field', true);
        // Display the custom field only when it is set with a value
        if (!empty($field_value)) {
            echo '<div class="custom-field">' . __('Markup: ', 'woocommerce') . $field_value . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```